# A set of linear algebra questions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could you help me with these questions, I figured most of them out on my own, but I'm not completely sure if I'm correct.

a) $A=\begin{bmatrix}a^2&ab&ac\\ ab&b^2&bc\\ ac&bc&c^2\end{bmatrix}$ where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}\backslash \left\{0\right\}$.

Does $A$ have *i)* three real eigenvalues *ii)* complex eigenvalues *iii)* two non-zero eigenvalues *iv)* one non-zero eigenvalue. **NOTE: you're not to calculate the eigenvalues**.

**My approach:**
I can see that this matrice is symmetric, thus it's eigenvalues must be real, so option *ii)* is false, next it's singular, thus one of the eigenvalues is $0$, the first pivot $a^2$ is positive thus one of the eigenvalues must be positive, also the matrix is only positively semi-defined, it's second minor $d_2=0$ so my guess is that the answer is *iv)*, and that the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$ has algebraic multiplicity 2.

**QUESTION 1** Does the number of minors $d_i$ that turn out to be zero equal the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda = 0$?

b) If $M=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&2\\ 0&2&2\\ 0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $V=\left\{Mx:x\in \mathbb{R}^3\right\}$ whatis the dimension of V?

**My approach** $x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ x_3\end{bmatrix}$, so by multiplication we get: $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1+2x_3+2x_3\\ \:2x_2+2x_3\\ x_2+\:x_3\end{bmatrix}=x_1\begin{bmatrix}\:1\\ \:0\\ \:0\end{bmatrix}+\left(x_2+x_3\right)\begin{bmatrix}\:2\\ \:2\\ \:1\end{bmatrix}=span\left(\begin{bmatrix}\:1\\ \:\:0\\ \:\:0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}\:2\\ \:\:2\\ \:\:1\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

Thus $dimV=2$

c)if $A=\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\ 0&2&0\\ 0&0&3\end{bmatrix}$ which of these is a subspace?

[image]

**QUESTION 2** I think *i) and ii)* are subspaces, but what about the other two?

Comment: These questions are unrelated, it would be better if you asked them separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

- For a), it is useful to note that $A = xx^T$, where $x$ is the column-vector $x = (a,b,c)$.  No, the number of minors that are zero is not necessarily the multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue; if you wanted to use minors, you'd have to show that every $2 \times 2$ submatrix has determinant zero.  You should instead find the rank of the matrix through the usual methods (e.g. row-reduction).
- For b), your approach is fine
- For c), i) is indeed a subspace, and ii) is certainly a subspace since it is the entire space.  iii) is also a subspace (since the map $X \mapsto trace(AX)$ is linear) and iv) is **not** a subspace.

Comment: Thanks sir, however your answer for a) makes me questions, what is the correlation between the matrix rank and eigenvalues, can you link me an article if the answer is long? The only thing I know for sure that if it doesn't have a 'full rank' then it has a 0 eigenvalue for sure.

Comment: The dimension of the nullspace of $(A - \lambda I)$ is the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Thus, by noticing that our matrix $A = A - 0 \cdot I$ rank $1$, we may conclude that $A$ has nullspace dimension $2$, so that the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ is $2$.

Comment: Notice also for iv) that since $A$ is invertible, $iv)$ is just the set of $X$ with $\det(X) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

obviously,

$A = C\times D=\begin{bmatrix}a &0 &0\\ 0&b&0 \\0&0&c \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix}a &a&a \\b &b &b \\ c&c&c\end{bmatrix}$, where $rank(C)=3$ for $a\neq b\neq c$, and $rank(D)=1$. From the rank property, we can see $rank(A)=rank(CD)\leq \min(rank(C),rank(D))$. Then you can get your results. Hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

a) I agree.
I am not sure about your conjecture how the minors relate to the multiplicity of $\lambda=0$  However, I can eyeball two eigenvectors for $\lambda=0$

$v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} b\\-a\\0\end{bmatrix}, v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} c\\0\\-a\end{bmatrix}$

b) looks fine

c) For each $X$, Suppose $P,Q \in X$
then for example iii) if $trace (AP)=0$ and $trace (AQ)=0$
does $trace (kAP) = 0$ for scalar $k$
and does $trace (A(P+Q)) = trace (AP+AQ) = 0$? 
If so, then X is closed under addition and scalar multiplication and hence a subspace.

Comment: So um is there any other way to guess/know the multiplicity of $\lambda=0$? Also the way you put it would that mean that all for are subspace in problem c?